# How can I declare Signal() with optional keyword arguments in pyside6?

Tags: python, signals-slots, pyside6

I am trying to declare a Signal with three bool type optional keyword arguments. I have tried some ways as suggested by ChatGPT and the help function but no luck so far.

```py
my_signal = Signal(**{'arg1': Optional[bool] = False, 'arg2': Optional[bool] = False, 'arg3': Optional[bool] = False})

my_signal = Signal(arg1=Optional[bool], arg2=Optional[bool], arg3=Optional[bool])

my_signal = Signal(arg1=bool, arg2=bool,arg3=bool)
```

I get the following errors respectively.

```
'invalid syntax error'.

TypeError: QtCore.Signal{name, arguments}() takes at most 2 keyword arguments (3 given)

TypeError: 'arg1' is an invalid keyword argument for QtCore.Signal{name, arguments}()
```

Could anybody help with a correct a syntax.

Comment: And that's a further reason for which using AI (at least right now) is unreliable for asking generic/beginner questions, unless it has been *specifically* trained for the purpose, the context and the toolkit (which means that who is asking already has enough experience, and won't ask certain questions). That said: you can't, at least easily and not by default. While Qt allows creating signals with default values for their arguments, neither PyQt or PySide signal constructors provide that feature. You only have signal overloads, and they don't support keyworded arguments with default values.

Comment: That doesn't mean that it's completely impossible: there are some possible (and *hacky*) workarounds, but I am under the impression that you just want to save some code writing. If that's the case, just don't: Qt is known to be *very* verbose in its syntax (long class names and functions); you could achieve the above using signal overloads, assuming that the default arguments are always in the same order, you'd need to explicitly write the overload signature for that signal, making the "less chars" reason quite pointless, and the code unnecessarily cumbersome. That's not worth it.

Comment: Instead, consider a more simple approach: if you want a "simple form" for emitting a signal, create a dedicated function that has keyworded arguments, and emit the signal from there. For instance: `def emitSignal(self, arg1=False, arg2=False, arg3=False):` `self.signal.emit(arg1, arg2, arg3)` and then call `emitSignal()` using positional/keyword arguments according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

since `Optional` means `bool` or `None` you would have to overload the signal and AFAIK doesn't exist in the Python bindings.

here are two alternatives (that are way simpler):

#### 1. properties:

you have a private variable and when it changes you emit
a signal that notify that the property have changed.
i.e

```py
class Foo(QObject):
    tripleBoolChanged = Signal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)
        self._triple_bool: tuple[bool | None, bool | None, bool | None] = (None, None, None)
        self.tripleBoolChanged.connect(self.something_that_needs_triple_bool)

    def set_triple_bool(self, a: bool | None = None, b: bool | None = None, c: bool | None = None):
        self._triple_bool = a, b, c
        self.tripleBoolChanged.emit()
    def triple_bool(self):
        return self._triple_bool
    def something_that_needs_triple_bool(self):
       print(self.triple_bool())
```

#### 2. Container class.

Create a class that contains that triple bool and emit the instance.
i.e

```py
class FooAlternative(QObject):
    @dataclasses.dataclass
    class TripleBool:
        a: bool | None = None
        b: bool | None = True
        c: bool | None = False


    tripleBoolChanged = Signal(TripleBool)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)
        self.tripleBoolChanged.connect(self.something_that_needs_triple_bool)

    def emit_triple_bool(self, a: bool | None = None, b: bool | None = None, c: bool | None = None):
        tb = self.TripleBool(a, b, c)
        self.tripleBoolChanged.emit(tb)
        
    def something_that_needs_triple_bool(self, tb: TripleBool):
       print("foo alternative:", tb)
```

[Full code here](https://github.com/nrbnlulu/Qt-answers/tree/master/optional-bool-75529778)